# Accessing to a member property by using linq expression factory methods

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

For purposes of my project i need to some linq query to an entitie, i am using expression factory methods to build dynamic filter predicate.

Considering this code :

```
public class mother{
  public int age {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
  public child child {get; set;}
}

public class child{
  public int age {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
}

//predicate builder
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetChildNamePredicat<T>(){
  var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "param");

  // age property of mother class
  var motherAgeProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, typeof(T).GetProperty("age"));

  // name property of child class
  var motherChildProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, typeof (t).GetProperty("child"));
  var childNameProperty = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(motherChildProperty , typeof (child).GetProperty("name "));

   BinaryExpression motherAgeCondition;
   BinaryExpression childNameCondition;

  //building condition mother age >= 40 and child name = junior
  var motherAgeConst = Expression.Constant(40, typeof(int));
  var childNameConst = Expression.Constant("junior", typeof(string));
  motherAgeCondition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(motherAgeProperty, motherAgeConst);
  childNameCondition= Expression.Equal(childNameProperty, childNameConst);
  var mergeCondition = Expression.AndAlso(motherAgeCondition , childNameCondition);

  //return expression
  return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(mergeCondition , param);
}

var myPredicate = GetChildNamePredicat<mother>();
```

This code compile with success but it seem to not be fonctionnal, no result...
By using  variable's spy on "myPredicate", i can see lambda debug view like this :

```
.Lambda
#Lambda1<System.Func`2[myNameSpace.mother,System.Boolean]>(myNameSpace.mothe $e) { $e.age >= 40 &&  ($e.child).name == "junior" }
```

($e.child) ... it so strange

Do you know another solution or/and have any idea about accessing to child name property from mother parameter ?

Thx for advance!

Comment: You've used the parameter `e` in `MakeMemberAccess` for `motherChildProperty`, not `param` - is this a typo?

Comment: Your expression looks fine - are you sure your data source contains a `mother` over 40 with a `child` called "junior"?

Comment: Yes, i verifying by doing query on my db with SqlServer Management Studio.

Comment: What happens if you replace `myPredicate` in your LINQ query Where clause with a normal lambda?

Comment: It will work, but to avoid code duplication i refactoring this lambda to a function. Code above is just example to illustrate my problem, real code it's a bit more complex.

Comment: Your expression creation is correct - the problem must be somewhere else.